# How I can optimize query with where index?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

I have query

```
select `price`, `asset_id` 
from `history_average_pairs` 
where `currency_id` = 1 
  and date(`created_at`) >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
group by hour(created_at), date(created_at), asset_id 
order by `created_at` asc
```

And table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS history_average_pairs (
  id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  asset_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  currency_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  market_cap bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  price double(20,6) NOT NULL,
  volume bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  circulating bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  change_1h double(8,2) NOT NULL,
  change_24h double(8,2) NOT NULL,
  change_7d double(8,2) NOT NULL,
  created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  updated_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  total_supply bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE history_average_pairs
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (id),
  ADD KEY history_average_pairs_currency_id_asset_id_foreign (currency_id,asset_id),
ALTER TABLE history_average_pairs
  MODIFY id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

It contains more than 10 000 000 rows, and query takes

Showing rows 0 - 24 (32584 total, Query took 27.8344 seconds.)

But without `currency_id = 1`, it takes like 4 sec.

**UPDATE 1**

Okey, I updated key from `currency_id, asset_id` to `currency_id, asset_id, created_at` and it takes

Showing rows 0 - 24 (32784 total, Query took 6.4831 seconds.)

Its much faster, any proposal to do it more faster?
`GROUP BY` here to take only first row for every hour.
For example:

```
19:01:10 
19:02:14 
19:23:15
```

I need only 19:01:10

Comment: Put a key on currency_id

Comment: create a combined index on `currency_id` + `created_at`. currency_id will help in filtering and created_at will help for the filter and the order by

Comment: The `GROUP BY` statement is invalid as you do not have aggregate functions in the query. What is it that you are trying to achieve with it?

Comment: Any chance you could upload a dump of the table?

Comment: @Julio sorry, but no

Comment: Please read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ for some guidance about how to ask questions like this. AND, please avoid editing your question to expand it after you have an answer. You can always ask another question.

Comment: Change the order of your index. Try `currency_id, created_at, asset_id` instead of `currency_id, asset_id, created_at`. Remember, your filtering predicate should discard rows at the earliest possible opportunity.

Comment: I agree with slaakso; the query is invalid. MySQL should raise an error, but instead it silently applies `ANY_VALUE` on the price and the created_at you are selecting, i.e. it arbitrarily picks the values from the rows in a group. So, rather than trying to get the incorrect query faster, you should fix it. If it really is `ANY_VALUE` you want, then make this explicit. As you seem to have trouble with aggregation, I suggest you set ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode - at least until you've mastered it. Only when the query is fixed should you look at its performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rephrase the filtering predicate to avoid using expressions on columns. For example:

```
select max(`price`) as max_price, `asset_id` 
from `history_average_pairs` 
where `currency_id` = 1 
  and created_at >= date_add(curdate(), interval - 7 day)
group by hour(created_at), date(created_at), asset_id 
order by `created_at` asc
```

Then, this query could be much faster if you added the index:

```
create index ix1 on `history_average_pairs` (`currency_id`, created_at);
```

Answer (score 2):

You must make the test "sargeable"; change

```
date(`created_at`) >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

to

```
created_at >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

Then the optimal index is

```
INDEX(currency_id,   -- 1st because of "=" test
      created_at,    -- 2nd to finish out WHERE
      asset_id)      -- only for "covering"
```

When designing an index, it is *usually* best to handle the `WHERE` first.

The `GROUP BY` cannot use the index.  Did you really want the hour first?

"I need only 19:01:10" is unclear, so I have not factored that in.  Where's the date?  Where's the asset_id?  See "only_full_group_by".  Do you need "groupwise max"?

Making the `ORDER BY` have the same columns as the `GROUP BY` avoids a sort.  (In your query, the order may be slightly different, but it probably does not matter.)

Datatype issues...

- `BIGINT` takes 8 bytes; `INT` takes only 4 bytes and is *usually* big enough.  Shrinking the table provides some speed.
- `double(8,2)` takes 8 bytes -- Don't use `(m,n)` on `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`; it adds an extra rounding.  Perhaps you meant `DECIMAL(8,2)`, which takes 4 bytes.